# How to change button's drawable background's direction which uses XML

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I have 2 buttons ( left and right ) with one background drawable.

The background has corners on the right side.

I don't want to create one more background just for a change the side of the corners to left, so how can I rotate the background with corners on right in the XML file to put the corners on left?

I've tried to add android:rotation="180dp" but it's not worked for me:

```
       <Button
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_buttons"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_buttons"
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

code for the drawable background as below

```
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/text_color" android:width="0.5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

[image]

Comment: Would be perfect if you share a screenshot of what you have and what you expect

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Added.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom background. You can use the standard `MaterialButton` in the Material Components Library and apply a **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:strokeWidth="..."
        app:strokeColor="@color/...."
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/left"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:strokeWidth="..."
        app:strokeColor="@color/...."
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/right"/>
```

with:

```
<style name="right">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="left">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]